# Where does the MySQL database store its data?

Tags: mysql, database, file

For SQLite, the program directly put the database information - schema/data into a file. 
In command line prompt, it's

% sqllite3

So How about for MySQL database? Even for a local usage, I need to set up a client-server login to access the database. Anyway, the data has to be put somewhere on the disk to take some space.

More specifically, how to configure the MySQL data storage location? If I need to move the MySQL data to another directory or disk partition, how to proceed?

Comment: Just saw a simliar topic is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802834/where-does-the-mysql-database-store-its-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `datadir` value in `my.cnf` file of your MySQL installation

If you are in Windows, probably you will find this file in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini` or where ever drive your MySQL installation in

If you are in Linux, probably you will find the file in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

You could check [here](http://www.mkyong.com/mysql/where-does-mysql-stored-the-data-in-my-harddisk/) for more info