# How do I share/use a MySQL database on two local host computers with no network using a flash drive?

Tags: mysql, database, localhost

**Objective/goal:**

My goal is to set up a few databases for some research projects that my workgroup is doing. The databases would only be used for my small workgroup (4 people) and network servers are not possible (i.e., Localhost only). Only one person would need access to the database at a time.

**Question:**

How do I share/use a MySQL database between 2-4 localhost computers with no network using a flash drive? Is this possible and is there any downside? Is there a better non-network solution? Are there any additional concerns programmatically?

**My potential solution:**

The plan is to run my Mysql data folder off a flash drive and just plug it into whichever computer needs to use the databases. I don't want to do the following [Copying MySQL Database to another machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916959/copying-mysql-database-to-another-machine), as I want one set of databases shared and not multiple copies. My plan was to move my data directory to the USB flash drive based on these posts [Where does the MySQL database store its data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802834/where-does-the-mysql-database-store-its-data) and [How can I move a MySQL database to another drive?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14320/how-can-i-move-a-mysql-database-to-another-drive). Everyone else would also set their data directory for there pc/localhost to the folder on the flash drive and whoever is working with the database would just plug the flash drive into their PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are considering the hardest solution which is a physical backup. Physical backups are not very portable if the different PC-s have different hardware characteristics. Either go for a logical backup (see mysqldump) or install a virtual machine with MySQL in the USB drive.

Comment: So I would just dump the back-up and the next user would import and redump after they are done? More or less just rewriting over top of the backup, so that there is one unified database?

Comment: Exactly. Copying the datadir from one pc to another is not like moving the datadir in the same installation from one dir to another. While it is possible, I wouldn't recommend it, unless you want to play DBA :)